# how to fix this error ""name":"ValidatorError","message":"Path `Name` is required.""

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server, web-deployment

I am trying to fetch data from client side when i make a post request I get this error , I am new to the mongoDB and Node.js please help
I don't understand this error that why this is coming please help to resolve it

this is my schema code
`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const signupTemplate = mongoose.Schema({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  Email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    Default: Date.now,
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("users", signupTemplate);
```

`

this is my router code

`

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const signedUpUser = new signUpTemplate({
    Name: req.body.Name,
    Phone: req.body.Phone,
    Email: req.body.Email,
    Password: req.body.Password,
  });

  console.log(req.body.Name);
  signedUpUser
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(err);
      // console.log('you made an error');
    });

  // res.send("User Registered successfully");
});
```

`

this is my form code
`

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
          <label for="Name">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" />
          <label for="Phoneno">Phone No.</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"id="Phoneno" name="Phone" />
          <label for="Email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control"id="Email" name="Email" />
          <label for="create-password">Create Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control"id="create-password" name="Password" />
          <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control"id="confirm-password" name=" Confirm-password" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
          <hr>
          <p style="display:inline;">Or continue with</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-google"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </form>
```

`

Comment: could you show your `app.js/server.js`?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a name to the data you sent.. Because you set the name as a requirement in the model, you won't be able to post your data unless you pass the name.
The required field in the model can be set to false if the Name is not required

Answer (score 0):

Hey do you have the express urlencoded middleware in your index.js or server.js and if not add this line of code

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```